# Is it possible to manage calls on an iPhone?

Tags: ios, blocking, phone-call

I just would like to know if it is possible (and if yes how) to manage receiving calls on iPhone ?

For example, send automatically a call to the voice message service by activating an "in-app option" (for example a game), in order to not to be disturb during the game !

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Apple doesn't provide public API to manage call thru the third party app.

Comment: Damn it ! Any other "un-Official" way to do it ?

Comment: I don't know any unofficial ways to do this. Even if it possible, it is bad idea to use private API, because the app will be reject by Apple and it won't be published on the App Store.

Comment: Correct but it could be great to use to developp anything just for me :p. Anyone know a private API for that !!?? Thx